# Set quota template for the site collection using csom

Tags: sharepoint-server, storage-quota

I have a csom solution used to create site collection in sharepoint 2019 and want to set the quota template for newly created site collection. Is there any api or methods in csom to set site quota in client side?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this could be achieved in client side. We have to use servr side code to set the quota template.